How to push the performance of this compiled function
I have the function optvals solving for two variables. For the given example of variables, I need the program to run atmost in a millisecond.
The main part of the code is within the function optvals where I iterate over the two variables nu and eta and calculates the function ekert.  I'm not sure how I can parallelize the code within Compile.
Any optimization tips will be much appreciated!
EDIT
Heres the updated code. I have inlined the function gammaFuncekert within ekert. I have also rewritten the code to be more C like.  I'm currently at four milliseconds. Is it possible to beat this time? What optimization trick am I missing?
ekert = Compile[{{nu, _Real}, {eta, _Real}, {ntrials, _Real}, {nsucc, \
_Real}, {ntot, _Real}}, Module[{expr},

    expr = -2.0*(1.0/(ntot*(nsucc/ntrials + eta) + 1.0) + 
        1.0/(ntot - ntot*(nsucc/ntrials + eta) + 
           1.0))*((ntot - ntrials)^2*(nu - eta)^2 - 1.0);

    Exp[-2.0*ntot*ntrials*eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1.0)] + 
     Exp[If[expr < -70.0, 0.0, expr]]], 

   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];


optvals = 
  Compile[{{ntot, _Real}, {ntrials, _Real}, {nsucc, _Real}, {epspe, \
_Real}, {nutrials, _Real}, {etatrials, _Real}}, 
   Module[{serf, i, j, minVal, iStep, jStep, iMax, tempVal}, 

serf = Sqrt[ ntot*(ntrials + 1.0)* Log[1.0/epspe]/(2.0*ntrials^2.0*(ntot - ntrials))];

    minVal = serf;
    iStep = (serf - serf/3.0)/(nutrials - 1);
    jStep = (serf*0.999 - serf/4.0)/(etatrials - 1);
    
    For[i = serf/3.0, i <= serf, i += iStep, iMax = i*0.999;

     For[j = serf/4.0, j <= iMax, j += jStep, 
      tempVal = ekert[i, j, ntrials, nsucc, ntot];

      If[tempVal <= epspe && i < minVal, minVal = i];]];
    minVal], 

   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

ntot =  10^4.;
ntrials = 0.3 ntot;
nsucc = 0.05 ntrials;
epspe = 10^-15.;

optvals[ntot, ntrials, nsucc, epspe, 1000, 1000] // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.00686941, 0.0830119}*)

Original
gammaFuncekert = 
  Compile[{{merr, _Real, 0}, {m, _Real, 0}}, 
   1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1),
   RuntimeOptions -> {
     "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

ekert = Compile[{{nu, _Real, 0}, {eta, _Real, 0}, {ntrials, _Real, 
     0}, {nsucc, _Real, 0}, {ntot, _Real, 0}}, 
   Exp[-2 ntot ntrials  eta^2/(ntot - ntrials + 1)] + 
    Exp[If[-2 gammaFuncekert[ntot (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
         ntot] ((ntot - ntrials)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1) < -700, 
      0, -2 gammaFuncekert[ntot (nsucc/ntrials + eta), 
        ntot] ((ntot - ntrials)^2 (nu - eta)^2 - 1)]],
   RuntimeOptions -> {
     "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

optvals = 
  Compile[{{ntot, _Real, 0}, {ntrials, _Real, 0}, {nsucc, _Real, 
     0}, {epspe, _Real, 0}, {nutrials, _Real, 0}, {etatrials, _Real, 
     0}}, Module[{optvalues, etalist, nulist, serf, prob, tab, nuval, 
     etaval, epsval, eps, add}, optvalues = {1., 1.};
    serf = 
     Sqrt[ntot (ntrials + 1.) Log[
         1./epspe]/(2. ntrials^2. (ntot - ntrials))];
    nuval = serf;
    etaval = serf;
    Min[Flatten[
      Table[Table[
        If[ekert[i, j, ntrials, nsucc, ntot] <= epspe, i, serf], {j, 
         Range[serf/4, i, (i - serf/4)/(etatrials - 1)]}], {i, 
        Range[serf/3, serf, ( serf - serf/3)/(nutrials - 1)]}], 1]]],
   RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed",
     "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

ntot =  10^4.;
ntrials = 0.3 ntot;
nsucc = 0.05 ntrials;
epspe = 10^-15.;
optvals[ntot, ntrials, nsucc, epspe, 1000, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0155125, 0.0830119}*)



As politely as I can ask, why are you even writing Mathematica? There doesn't seem to be any deep dependence on Mathematica in this. Why aren't you just writing this in C, see if it runs in less than 0.001 seconds or not, and you can completely skip the question of why Mathematica isn't doing it for you.

Shouldn't your new version give exactly the same result as the original one? Or at least more digits?

@RolfMertig Yeah that was an issue with the specific constraints I used. It doesnt impact the performance that much. I have edited the code
